# Recursive function returning boolean, with a for loop inside

Tags: xquery

My data is a binary tree, and will check through every child, returning true if it finds the data i want, if not, it keeps looking for it.
In some way i want to return the variable @exists or something.. Well anyone might have a solution for my problem. I was thinking something like this but i couldn't get it to work! (code-snippet)

```
declare function local:test($id as xs:integer, $topic as xs:integer) as xs:boolean {
    let $exists := fn:false()
    for $x in ...
    return
        if .. then
            set exists to fn:true()
        else
            set exists to exists OR local:test($x,$topic)

    return @exists in some way  
};
```

Comment: You may be interested to look at my implementation of the Binary Search Tree data structure in XQuery 3.0 -- here: http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/the-binary-search-tree-data-structurehaving-fun-with-xpath-3-0/

Answer (score 2):

This is a case for an XQuery [quantified expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-quantified-expressions). Using that, your function translates to

```
declare function local:test($id as xs:integer, $topic as xs:integer) as xs:boolean
{
  some $x in ...
  satisfies
    if (..) then
      fn:true()
    else
      local:test($x,$topic)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned XQuery is a functional language. You can't just set variable and return it. Your query can be though rewritten like:

```
declare function local:test($id as xs:integer, $topic as xs:integer) as xs:boolean {
    exists(for $x in ...
           where (: here is condition expression on $x :)
           return $x)
};
```

Function `exists(Expr)` returns `true` if the value of `Expr` is not the empty sequence; otherwise, the function returns `false`.

In this case `exists` returns `true` if there is `$x` which meets specified condition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the values of variables in xquery.

Is your whole function not just this:

```
declare function local:test($topic as xs:integer) as xs:boolean {
     ... OR local:test($topic/...)
};
```

Comment: No, i have to loop trough different things and in some way return true or false